# GStreamer pipeline with Tee including two sink fails

Tags: c++, gstreamer, tee

Trying to implement GStreamer pipeline with Tee using following elements.

```
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN (pipeline), <rpicamsrc>, <capsfilter>, <h264parse>, tee, <queue>, <rtph264pay>, <fakesink>, <queue>, <avdec_h264>, <videoconvert>, <capsfilter>, <customplugin>, <fakesink>, nullptr);
```

For better understanding provided the element names. The purpose is to create Tee pipeline as follows:

```
rpicamsrc ! capsfilter ! h264parse ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! rtph264pay ! fakesink t. ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! capsfilter ! customplugin ! fakesink
```

But it fails always and doesn't report any error. But no video frames are captured. After some testing identified that fails for even this simple pipeline:

```
gst_element_link_many ( <rpicamsrc>, <capsfilter>, <h264parse>, <rtph264pay>, <fakesink>, nullptr))
```

Interesting is if I remove second *fakesink* from that above *gst_bin_add_many* line of code it works. Not sure what's the problem with this. Tried to use a different sink like autovideosink but no luck. When it fails it doesn't receive GST message type *GST_MESSAGE_ASYNC_DONE* in gst bus, but for success case it does. Gets *GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_CREATE*, *GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_ENTER* and *GST_MESSAGE_STREAM_START* for both failure and success case. What I am doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Try run your pipeline using gst-launch on terminal, set GST_DEBUG=4 to get log.

Answer (score 0):

[`gst_element_link_many()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#gst-element-link-many) is a convenient wrapper for a non-branched pipeline, meaning that it links one from next, to next. It does not know that you want to link the tee element in the middle of the pipeline with multiple elements.  For example in your case, it tries to connect the `fakesink` to the `queue` in the middle of your pipeline.

**Easy way**

You can use [`gst_parse_launch()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch) to let GStreamer figure out what links to what.

**By your hands**

If you have an element like `tee`, you must use  [`gst_element_link()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#gst-element-link) or [`gst_element_link_pads()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#gst-element-link-pads) to tell GSreamer that which element connect to which.

It is possible to create two pipelines with `gst_element_link_many()`,

```
rpicamsrc → capsfilter → h264parse → tee → queue → rtph264pay → fakesink

queue → avdec_h264 → videoconvert → capsfilter → customplugin→ fakesink
```

and then, link the `tee` element in the above to the below with `gst_element_link_pads()`.